# Unexpected error while installing

Tags: installation

I have downloaded the Drupal and was installing it first time, initially it was giving me an error message in the database base configuration step and then after that started giving the

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Can anyone tell me what might be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  Please edit your question and provide the exact steps and environment information to reproduce this issue. Many thanks

Comment: If you're on D8, add `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';` to /sites/default/settings.php so you can see the actual/real error as its impossible to tell with the current error message.

Comment: Message `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.` indicates there is likely a PHP error which prevent the installation from finishing. Please check https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/show-all-errors-while-developing out, it should apply to Drupal 8 as well.